# How to show "Done" button on iOS number pad keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-input

There is no "Done" button on the `.numberPad` Keyboard Type. When a user finishes entering numeric information in a text field, how can I make the number pad disappear?

I could get a "Done" button by using the default keyboard, but then users would have to switch to the numeric keys in order to input numbers. Is there a way to show a "Done" button on the number pad?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

**Another solution. Perfect if there are other non-number pad text fields on the screen.**

[image: inputAccessoryView]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)]];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
    NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: No doubt the best way of accomplishing this. Explicitly because it adheres to Apples strict HIG.

Comment: The other solution is very brittle in terms of any graphical changes to the onscreen keyboard will break it.

Comment: If there are multiple text fields, how do I determine which UITextField is being edited?

Comment: Define your UITextField in the .h as an instance variable.

Comment: Has anyone found a way using this solution to color the bar and buttons?

Comment: @BenPotter You would set the barTint for the bar color and tint color for the text. You could also create the UIBarButton items out side of the intializer and set the color for them explicitly there.

Comment: The other solutions look like hard code. They are unstable。

Comment: This is by far the correct answer. If you are using ARC, one solution for multiple UITextFields is to create the toolbar or view in IB, and connect it to a variable in your header. Then when your view loads you set the inputAccessoryView to that variable in your header.

Comment: It's decent but if there are other non-number pad text fields, what makes this perfect in that situation?  One drawback is that the keyboard for the phone pad is larger than other keyboards.

Comment: Note that instead of `320` for width, you should be using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width`

Answer (score 56):

Here is an adaptation for Luda's answer for Swift:

In the declaration of your UIViewController subclass put

```
let numberToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
```

in ViewDidLoad put:

```
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    numberToolbar.items=[
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "hoopla"),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Apply", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "boopla")
    ]

    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()

    textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar //do it for every relevant textfield if there are more than one
```

and the add the functions hoopla and hoopla (feel free to choose other names, just change the selector names in ViewDidLoad accordingly

```
func boopla () {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func hoopla () {
    textField.text=""
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: `UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered` is deprecated since iOS 8.0. `UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain` is suggested instead.

Comment: Selectors should be updated to:
#selector(YourViewController.boopla)

Comment: Jonny and David are probably right. I'm not programming for iOS anymore so I don't follow the changes. If anyone posts an updated solution I'll refer to it in an edit.

Answer (score 23):

A **Swift 3** solution using an extension. Ideal if you have several numeric `UITextField` objects in your app as it gives the flexibility to decide, for each `UITextField`, whether to perform a custom action when *Done* or *Cancel* is tapped.

[image]

```
//
//  UITextField+DoneCancelToolbar.swift
//

import UIKit

extension UITextField {
    func addDoneCancelToolbar(onDone: (target: Any, action: Selector)? = nil, onCancel: (target: Any, action: Selector)? = nil) {     
        let onCancel = onCancel ?? (target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped))
        let onDone = onDone ?? (target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))

        let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.barStyle = .default
        toolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: onCancel.target, action: onCancel.action),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: onDone.target, action: onDone.action)
        ]
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    // Default actions:  
    func doneButtonTapped() { self.resignFirstResponder() }
    func cancelButtonTapped() { self.resignFirstResponder() }
}
```

Example of usage using the default actions:

```
//
// MyViewController.swift
//

@IBOutlet weak var myNumericTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet { myNumericTextField?.addDoneCancelToolbar() }
}
```

Example of usage using a custom *Done* action:

```
//
// MyViewController.swift
//

@IBOutlet weak var myNumericTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet { 
        myNumericTextField?.addDoneCancelToolbar(onDone: (target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTappedForMyNumericTextField))) 
    }
}

func doneButtonTappedForMyNumericTextField() { 
    print("Done"); 
    myNumericTextField.resignFirstResponder() 
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The trick I've seen used is to make a custom transparent button the size of the whole view and then in its click method, have the text field resign first responder. So the user can click anywhere outside of the field to dismiss the keypad.

Comment: I have done this in addition to the Return key.  It makes for a much more user-friendly app.  I like to give both the return keys and the click anywhere return methods.

Comment: now that we have UIGestureRecognizers, just set up a tap gesture recognizer on the main viewcontroller view and have it send endEditing:YES to it's view.  This will close the keyboard for every textfield that the keyboard could be servicing, when touching outside the keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

Below is an overhaul of Luda's answer with the following changes:

- the accessory view is automatically sized to the width of the application frame
- the deprecated constant `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is avoided
- the "Done" button is instantiated as a `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`

Currently the "Done" button is centered in the accessory view. You can position it at left or right by deleting the space on the pertinent side.

I have omitted a "Cancel" button because the default keyboard doesn't have one either. If you do want a "Cancel" button, I suggest that you instantiate it as a `UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel` and that you make sure you're not discarding the original value in your text field. The "Cancel" behavior implemented in Luda's answer, which overwrites the value with a blank string, may not be what you want.

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  float appWidth = CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame);
  UIToolbar *accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, appWidth, 0.1 * appWidth)];
  UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                            target:nil
                            action:nil];
  UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(selectDoneButton)];
  accessoryView.items = @[space, done, space];
  self.valueField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
}

- (void)selectDoneButton {
  [self.valueField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

For more information about building accessory views, see the Apple documentation on [custom views for data input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html). You will probably want to consult the reference pages on [UIToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/) and [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/) as well.

Comment: `[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame` is deprecated in iOS 9. Use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`

Answer (score 11):

The solution in [UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad and missing return key](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) works great but only if there are no other non-number pad text fields on the screen.

I took that code and turned it into an UIViewController that you can simply subclass to make number pads work. You will need to get the icons from the above link.

NumberPadViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NumberPadViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
    UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
    UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;

- (IBAction)numberPadDoneButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

and NumberPadViewController.m:

```
#import "NumberPadViewController.h"

@implementation NumberPadViewController

@synthesize numberPadDoneImageNormal;
@synthesize numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
@synthesize numberPadDoneButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    if ([super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle] == nil)
        return nil;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
        self.numberPadDoneImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"];
        self.numberPadDoneImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"];
    } else {        
        self.numberPadDoneImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"];
        self.numberPadDoneImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"];
    }        
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Add listener for keyboard display events
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];     
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    // Add listener for all text fields starting to be edited
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                      object:nil];      
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                      object:nil];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (UIView *)findFirstResponderUnder:(UIView *)root {
    if (root.isFirstResponder)
        return root;    
    for (UIView *subView in root.subviews) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [self findFirstResponderUnder:subView];        
        if (firstResponder != nil)
            return firstResponder;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITextField *)findFirstResponderTextField {
    UIResponder *firstResponder = [self findFirstResponderUnder:[self.view window]];
    if (![firstResponder isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        return nil;
    return (UITextField *)firstResponder;
}

- (void)updateKeyboardButtonFor:(UITextField *)textField {

    // Remove any previous button
    [self.numberPadDoneButton removeFromSuperview];
    self.numberPadDoneButton = nil;

    // Does the text field use a number pad?
    if (textField.keyboardType != UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad)
        return;

    // If there's no keyboard yet, don't do anything
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] < 2)
        return;
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

    // Create new custom button
    self.numberPadDoneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.numberPadDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    self.numberPadDoneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = FALSE;
    [self.numberPadDoneButton setImage:self.numberPadDoneImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.numberPadDoneButton setImage:self.numberPadDoneImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.numberPadDoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberPadDoneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Locate keyboard view and add button
    NSString *keyboardPrefix = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2 ? @"<UIPeripheralHost" : @"<UIKeyboard";
    for (UIView *subView in keyboardWindow.subviews) {
        if ([[subView description] hasPrefix:keyboardPrefix]) {
            [subView addSubview:self.numberPadDoneButton];
            [self.numberPadDoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberPadDoneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[note object]];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}

- (IBAction)numberPadDoneButton:(id)sender {
    UITextField *textField = [self findFirstResponderTextField];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [numberPadDoneImageNormal release];
    [numberPadDoneImageHighlighted release];
    [numberPadDoneButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple numeric fields, I suggest subclassing UITextField to create a NumericTextField that always displays a numeric keyboard with a done button. Then, simply associate your numeric fields with this class in the Interface Builder and you won't need any additional code in any of your View Controllers. The following is Swift 3.0 class that I'm using in Xcode 8.0.

```
class NumericTextField: UITextField {
   let numericKbdToolbar = UIToolbar()

    // MARK: Initilization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialize()
    }

    // Sets up the input accessory view with a Done button that closes the keyboard
    func initialize()
    {
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad

        numericKbdToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let callback = #selector(NumericTextField.finishedEditing)
        let donebutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: callback)
        numericKbdToolbar.setItems([space, donebutton], animated: false)
        numericKbdToolbar.sizeToFit()
        self.inputAccessoryView = numericKbdToolbar
    }

    // MARK: On Finished Editing Function
    func finishedEditing()
    {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
class NumericTextField: UITextField {
    let numericKbdToolbar = UIToolbar()

    // MARK: Initilization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialize()
    }

    // Sets up the input accessory view with a Done button that closes the keyboard
    func initialize()
    {
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad

        numericKbdToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let callback = #selector(NumericTextField.finishedEditing)
        let donebutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: self, action: callback)
        numericKbdToolbar.setItems([space, donebutton], animated: false)
        numericKbdToolbar.sizeToFit()
        self.inputAccessoryView = numericKbdToolbar
    }

    // MARK: On Finished Editing Function
    @objc func finishedEditing()
    {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer your sub-class solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the most recent code.  Simply include 
    #import "UIViewController+NumPadReturn.h" in your viewController.

Here is the .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (NumPadReturn)



@end
```

And the .m

```
#import "UIViewController+NumPadReturn.h"


@implementation UIViewController (NumPadReturn)

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    // add observer for the respective notifications (depending on the os version)
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];     
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)addButtonToKeyboard {
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    } else {        
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"doneButton");
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}



@end
```

Comment: this seems to work on the simulator but on the device... neither can I see the DONE button nor anything happens when I tap the empty space... any idea?

Comment: Wow, please don't use this code. You overrode class methods from within a category, which is going to cause the "real" viewDidLoad, etc from your UIViewController class to be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

A much easier solution

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [textViewInstance1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textViewInstance2 resignFirstResponder];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found [@user1258240's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28707555/901156) to be pretty concise given this is not as simple as setting a `returnKeyType` property.

Just wanted to contribute my own "re-usable" approach to this:

```
func SetDoneToolbar(field:UITextField) {
    let doneToolbar:UIToolbar = UIToolbar()

    doneToolbar.items=[
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    ]

    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    field.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SetDoneToolbar(field: UITextField_1)
    SetDoneToolbar(field: UITextField_2)
    SetDoneToolbar(field: UITextField_3)
    SetDoneToolbar(field: UITextField_N)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 3.0** A different flavor, using parts of some previous answers.

```
func addToolbarToNumberPad()
{
    let numberPadToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()

    numberPadToolbar.isTranslucent = true
    numberPadToolbar.items=[
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelAction)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.customAction)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction)),
    ]

    numberPadToolbar.sizeToFit()

    textField.inputAccessoryView = numberPadToolbar
}

func cancelAction()
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func customAction()
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func doneAction()
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.addToolbarToNumberPad()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I describe one solution for iOS 4.2+ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401436/when-will-this-numberpad-keyboard-issue-is-going-to-be-solved-help/5767029#5767029) but the dismiss button fades in after the keyboard appears.  It's not terrible, but not ideal either.

The solution described in the question linked above includes a more elegant illusion to dismiss the button, where I fade and vertically displace the button to provide the appearance that the keypad and the button are dismissing together.

Answer (score 2):

The **simplest** way is:
Create **custom transparent button** and place it in left down corner, which will have same `CGSize` as empty space in `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`. Toggle (show / hide) this button on textField `becomeFirstResponder`, on button click respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest solution I have come across. I have learnt this from Beginning iOS 5 Development book.

Assuming the number field is called `numberField`.

1. In `ViewController`, add the following method:

   ```
   -(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender;
   ```
2. In `ViewController.m`, add the following code:

   ```
   -(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender
   {

        [numberField resignFirstResponder];

   }
   ```
3. Go back to `nib` file.
4. Open `Utilities` pan.
5. Open the `Identity inspector` under `Utilities` pan.
6. Click on the `View` (in nib file) once. Make sure you have not clicked on any of the items in the view. For the sake of clarification, you should see UIView under `Class` in `Identity inspector`.
7. Change the class from UIView to UIControl.
8. Open `Connection Inspector`.
9. Click and drag `Touch Down` and drop the arrow on `File Owner` icon. (FYI... File Owner icon is displayed on the left of `View` and appears as a hollow cube with yellow frame.)
10. Select the method: `closeKeyboard`.
11. Run the program.

Now when you click anywhere on background of `View`, you should be able to dismiss the keyboard.

Hope this helps you solve your problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I modified Bryan's solution to be a little more robust, so that it would play nicely with other types of keyboards that could appear in the same view.  It's described here:

[Create a DONE button on the iOS numpad UIKeyboard](http://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/tutorial-creating-a-done-button-on-the-iphone-number-pad-keyboard/)

I'd try to explain it here, but most of it is code to look at that wouldn't easily fit here

Comment: This was the best solution that I found for XCode 4.5 and it works with iOS 6.0.
It adds a DONE button to the numeric keyboard.
Go to the original post to get the DONE button graphics. http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance the number of numbers to be entered (e.g. a 4-digit PIN) you could auto-dismiss after 4 key presses, as per my answer to this similar question:

[dismissing Number Pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127104/dismissing-number-pad/16589216#16589216)

No need for an additional done button in this case.

Answer (score 2):

We can also make the ***"user touched somewhere else"*** solution even simpler if we just tell our view controller's view to end editing:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
 { 
      [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

      [self.view endEditing:YES]; //YES ignores any textfield refusal to resign
 }
```

... assuming that "touching elsewhere dismisses the keyboard" is desired behavior for any other editable fields on the view as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.2 I use this

```
func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50))

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.finishDecimalKeypad))

    var items: [UIBarButtonItem]? = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items?.append(flexSpace)
    items?.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    self.productPrice.inputAccessoryView=doneToolbar
}

func finishDecimalKeypad() {
    self.productPrice?.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All those implementation about finding the keyboard view and adding the done button at the 3rd row (that is why button.y = 163 b/c keyboard's height is 216) are fragile because iOS keeps change the view hierarchy. For example none of above codes work for iOS9.

I think it is more safe to just find the topmost view, by [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject], and just add the button at bottom left corner of it, doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-53, 106, 53);// portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 / I used Dx_'s answer. However, I wanted this functionality on all keyboards. So in my base class I put the code:

```
func addDoneButtonForTextFields(views: [UIView]) {
    for view in views {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            let doneToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50))

            let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            let done = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))

            var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
            items.append(flexSpace)
            items.append(done)

            doneToolbar.items = items
            doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

            textField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
        } else {
            addDoneButtonForTextFields(view.subviews)
        }
    }
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    dismissKeyboardForTextFields(self.view.subviews)
}

func dismissKeyboardForTextFields(views: [UIView]) {
    for view in views {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            dismissKeyboardForTextFields(view.subviews)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call addDoneButtonForTextFields on self.view.subviews in viewDidLoad (or willDisplayCell if using a table view) to add the Done button to all keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let pickerView = UIPickerView()
   
 var yearpickerToolbar: UIToolbar?
   
    func createPickerView() {
          
           pickerView.delegate = self
           textfield.inputView = pickerView }
   
   
     func dismissPickerView() {
           let toolBar = UIToolbar()
           toolBar.sizeToFit()
   
           toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
           textfield.delegate = self
   
   
   yearpickerToolbar = UIToolbar()
           yearpickerToolbar?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
   
           //add buttons
           let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action:#selector(cancelBtnClicked(_:)))
           cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
           let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
           
           let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain , target: self, action: #selector(self.doneBtnClicked(_ :) ))
           doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
   
           doneButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
   UIColor.black], for: .normal)
           cancelButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
   UIColor.black], for: .normal)
           
           yearpickerToolbar?.items = [cancelButton, flexSpace, doneButton]
           textfield.inputAccessoryView = yearpickerToolbar }
   
   @objc func cancelBtnClicked(_ button: UIBarButtonItem?) {
           self.view.endEditing(true)
           
       }
   
       @objc func doneBtnClicked(_ button: UIBarButtonItem?) {
           self.view.endEditing(true)
       }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.