# iPhone SDK NumberPad custom inputView for done button

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Currently I have a textfield, which pulls up a NumberPad keyboard for input.

I want the NumberPad keyboard layout, but I need a button to resign that responder.

Is there a way to code the UITextField so that it has a NumberPad keyboard and the space on the left of the keyboard which is blank is replaced with a 'Done', 'Send' or 'Go' button.

Or do I need to create a custom inputView for the UITextField?

I would have thought since there is a blank key on the NumberPad apple would have made it useful for something.

Comment: [Duplicate question, please look at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone) [Here is a link to a way to create such a button](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key)

Answer (score 2):

Just try having a `UIToolBar` with a done button on it as the `inputAccessoryView` of the text field. In the button click event provide the code to dismiss the keyboard. Think that should suit you.

Or if you want to have a custom button drawn over the keyboard you can search here to get the solution

Answer (score 1):

The empty button is needed if you use phonePad. But you can add `inputAccessoryView` with 'Apply' and 'Cancel' buttons, and dismiss the number pad with then.

[image: inputAccessoryView]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                     nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
    NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a custom inputview now and assign it to the inputview property of your text field. I am currently researching it, but that is the right, approved way of doing it. It seems overkill just for changing a single button though.

Comment: http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

has updated content for iOS4.0