# Is it possible to add done button inside the keyboard in iphone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, textfield, programmatically-created

Currently i am working in iPhone application, Using UITextField to enter phone number, user enter the phone number, then how to hide the keyboard? because no return button here, Is it possible to add done button inside the keyboard, please help me

Thanks in Advance

[image: Below mentioned image for your reference, empty space in left corner to add done button, Is it possible?]

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to roll your own On-screen keyboard...

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, I had the same issue. however I didnt end up making a new OSKB but rather bound the "done" button on a unused key on the remote.

Maybe you can get the same behaviour if you try to use the back button as done and override onBackPressed();

Comment: i didn't understand your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) is to be a good tutorial about this.

Comment: this is great even for non ios devs.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [link.](http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) It shows how to add "Done" button in key board.

But I would suggest you to use `inputAccessoryView` instead. Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014964/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone-os-4).

And **Must read** [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246080/616094).

Comment: Good suggestion but from the UX perspective it's less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can add inputAccessoryView with 'Apply' and 'Cancel' buttons, and dismiss the number pad with then.

inputAccessoryView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                     nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
    NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using done button you can also hide numeric keyboard this way by touching anywhere on the view

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [yourtextfieldname resignFirstResponder];
}
```