# Dismiss a numeric keypad from a UITextField w/o a UIToolbarButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I know there has been some discussion here regarding [How to show button ‘Done’ on number pad on iPhone OS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014964/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone-os-4) to dismiss a number pad. I would like to find a way to dismiss the number keypad w/o having to add a UIToolbarButton. My UITextFields are zipcode and age.The mint.com iPhone app does this; so there has to be a way.

Here is my current code that adds the UIToolbarButton:

```
textField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
textField1.delegate = self;

//Create a toolbar to add to the textpad
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissZipKeyPad)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
textField1.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Comment: If you don't want a button for this, what event do you want to trigger the keyboard dismissal?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to dismiss the keypad when the user touches anywhere outside the text field:

```
- (void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
[view resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

I found it here:

http://remarkablepixels.com/blog/2011/1/23/dismiss-iphone-keyboard.html