# dismissing Number Pad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextfield

In my app I have a text field that takes some number input from user so i set the keyboard type to "Number Pad"but now i am stuck as to how should i dismiss it when user finishes giving input . i know i have to use the delegate method "textfieldShouldReturn" but the problem is that number pad dont have a return key.so is it necessary to add a custom done key on the keyboard or there is some other way out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show button 'Done' on number pad on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone)

Comment: but Kenny in that ans it is mentioned that we have to add return key i wanna know cant we do it without adding  done key

Comment: Of course you can do it without the Done key, just create a method to `-resignFirstResponder` (as in [@PurplePilot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127104/dismissing-number-pad/3127138#3127138)'s answer.)

Comment: thx Kenny.....but what is background tap and nameField there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a background tap

```
-(IBAction)backGroundTap:(id)sender
```

in the dot h and then in the dot m file

```
-(IBAction)backGroundTap:(id)sender
[nameField resignFirstResponder];
[numberField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: thx Purple.......but what is backgroundtap and nameField is the name of textfield? and what is nameField here?

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapBackground = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBackground:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapBackground];

Comment: To add background tap gesture recognizer

Answer (score 41):

**Another solution - Add `inputAccessoryView` to yourNumberTextFiled**

[image: inputAccessoryView]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                     nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
    NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

If you know the length of the number to be entered (e.g. a 4-digit PIN) you could auto-dismiss the keypad after 4 keys entered.

I hit a problem resigning the first responder after 4 keys (it would ignore the last keypress if you returned YES after resigning, so I added an async delay to the resign.

This code is in the UITextField delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    // max 4 keypresses
    if(range.location == 3){
        // async workaround for can't return YES after resignFirstResponder 
        [self performSelector:@selector(closeKeypad:)
                   withObject:textField
                   afterDelay:0.1
         ];
    }
    else if(range.location > 3){        
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void) closeKeypad:(UITextField*)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Grateful for this! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is pretty easy to implement and which is working for changing the input focus or for dismissing the keyboard.

Implement this function (and the delegate UITextFieldDelegate):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Then, when you want dismiss the keyboard or changing the focus, you just have to call a notifier like that :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(focusNextField:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.1];
```

And finally, dismiss the keyboard on this one :

```
- (void) focusNextField:(UITextField *) textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    // some code
}
```

Nothing else !