# how can I show only number format input in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am making simple application that will take hotel name and price of item, and I want to show the price in only number format, because it can not be in alphabatical format, so what should I do add in code so that only number will be inputted in the Price UITextField?

If you are not getting my question, you may ask anything again
I do appreciate if I will get proper way of doing this,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your text field to accept only the numbers, you can set it's `keyboardType` property to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

```
[yourTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

There are different types of keyboardTypes available, which you can refer in [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits).

Comment: but one issue is that how can UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad will dismiss when I finish typing in it ?

Comment: Are you implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` methods? If so, in the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, add the line `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]`. It will automatically dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: @Simon,   yes, but when the format is UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad then there is no return or DONE key, I can dismiss normal keyboard which is using for input of hotel name, but for price keyboard(UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad) I can't, help me out

Comment: Yes.. Sorry for my comment regarding dismissing number pad.. I haven't tried dismissing it before. But the following post has a solution for this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone..

Comment: they are bit complex, but let me check them, thanx, I have accepted your answer Sir :-)

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in the Interface Builder as well:

[image: Number pad2]

[image: Number pad2]