# How do i correct this warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

I was searching for a Done button for the Number Pad,then i saw this question:

[How to show "Done" button on iPhone number pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone)

I copied Archie's answer code into mine,and i get 2 warnings in this area:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[note object]];
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}
```

The warnings are:

> Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSNotification *', expected 'struct UITextField *'

How can i correct that? I tried to switch with a UITextField but it all messed up

Comment: This is why you don't just copy and paste code.

Comment: I didn't,i examined the code,but i didn't find errors. It may be that i'm new of this language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BoltClock suggested, it does seem a bit strange that Archie use a delegate method's name as a notification handler. The problem might be stemming from the fact that you must be adopting the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. If you've done so, remove the line observing the notification,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

and then edit make the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method while becoming the delegate of the text fields,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:textField]; 
}
```

Or alternatively, rename the occurrences of `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` with some other suitable method name

Comment: If you read the answer that the OP was referring to, it seems that post chose to use notifications instead of a text field delegate, for whatever strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

`textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not a notification, it is a delegate method. The expected signature is `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField`

Comment: the name there doesn't matter, its called BY the textfield when editing starts, the textfield will be passed as that parameter.

Comment: Okay,i'll test and let you know.