# show Done button on number pad for multiple UITextFields

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, xcode5, user-input

[@Luda's answer is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone/25492305#25492305), but I got stuck when I needed to use it for multiple text fields so I edited it as the following:

First, I get IBOutlets for each one of my textFields, say: textField1, textField2

Then I edited the code as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad:)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(sendToServer:)],
                     nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    textField1.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
    textField2.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad:(UITextField *)textField
{
   //here I use if/else to determine which textField was tapped
   if(textField == self.textField1)
   {
      //do some stuff
   }else //...

}

-(void) sendToServer:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //here I use if/else to determine which textField was tapped
   if(textField == self.textField1)
   {
      //do some stuff
   }else //...
}
```

Notice how I had to add the colons `:` to the `@selector` as e.g. `@selector(sendToServer:)` that way the correct TextField is passed as a parameter.

**BUT**

It's not working. the test fails: `if(textField == self.textField1)`. So does anyone know how to do this right?

**The question is: How do I know which textfield is being edited?**

Comment: I am hoping for a more direct answer than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api. By direct I mean a parameter to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your check `if (textField == self.textField)` is failing is because the argument passed by default to a UIBarButtonItem selector is actually the UIBarButtonItem itself. You can verify this by placing a breakpoint inside either selector method and examining the textField arguments.

One possible solution, without introducing any code to loop through subviews, would be to declare your view controller as a UITextFieldDelegate, and then modify your selectors as follows:

```
- (void)sendToServer:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem {
    [self.view endEditing:NO];
}
```

Then implement the delegate method textFieldShouldEndEditing:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // here you would determine which text field the UIBarButtonItem was associated with
   if(textField == self.textField1)
   {
       // your code here
       // and then, if you wanted to dismiss the keyboard
       return YES;
   } else {
       return NO;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use tag
like this:

```
textFiled1.tag = 1;
textFiled2.tag = 2;
```

//when your textfield begins editing, this method will be called.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

NSLog(@"tag ==%d",textField.tag);
if(textField.tag == 1){
   //do sth
  }

}
```

by the way, you should declare   UITextFieldDelegate  in your XX.h file