# enablesReturnKeyAutomatically is not working with numeric keypad

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uitextview, message

I am implementing a message composer as like iMessages.

`enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` of `UITextView` is not working.

I have set it as `textView.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;`

but when I tap on numeric keypad and start typing something and sent using my send button. the `textView` got empty but the send button (return button of `UITextView`) is still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

enablesReturnKeyAutomatically seems to only affect the uikeyboard, which in this case is a numeric keypad.  The default numeric keypad does not have a return key, so there is nothing to enable/disable.

It sounds like you have a separate send button in the view.  A workaround is inside  - textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: calculate what the new string will be with the replacementText and test if this new String is equal to @"".  If so, then sendButton.enabled = NO, else sendButton.enabled = YES.

Remember to set the UITextViewDelegate and to trim the new string of white space.

Comment: The issue is not with my sendButton. The issue is with keypad's send button.

Comment: By default, the numeric keypad doesn't have a send button.  Did you do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone ?  Could you post your code?

Comment: @Joshuna Gafni My key pad is normal one only. but once the user switches to keypad then also the submit button is visible.