# How to show Done on Decimal Pad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have a `UITextField` which is `Number Pad` and its properties look like

[image]

But when I run my application, I do not see `Done` on my screen

[image]

What is the issue? How can I get `Done` on `Decimal Pad`?

Comment: The Decimal pad doesn't show the return key (regardless of its label). You need to create a view with a button and make it the text field's `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: For inspiration, have a look [here](https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/tutorial-creating-a-done-button-on-the-iphone-number-pad-keyboard/) and on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone

Comment: Can you guide me to what's needed? Sorry I am new to it, any references I should read up?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found when doing something like this is to append an `inputAccessoryView` to the `UITextField`. That input accessory view can have a "Done" button on it that dismisses the keyboard for you. I don't think you should put a "Done" button on the key pad itself, because where would it go?

Here's how I've done it before:

```
- (void)setupKeyboardAccessory {
    UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar        = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];
    keyboardToolbar.backgroundColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexBarButton    = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton    = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self.patientAgeTextField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
    keyboardToolbar.items             = @[flexBarButton, doneBarButton];
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;
}
```