# Swift - Text Field Keyboard Return Key Not Working?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am fairly new to swift and was working on a project where I included a text field. When I tested out the app, I noticed that the keyboard return key doesn't work and I am unable to exit the keyboard. Is there a reason why it does this? Can the return key's functionality be implemented through swift?

Also, there is another app I was recently working on that I switched the keyboard of a text field to number pad, and I realize there is no return key on the number pad, so again, I can't seem to figure out how to exit it. How could I fix this?

Sorry, I am pretty new to apple devices as well...

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have so far.

Comment: Have you looked into `resignFirstResponder()`?

Comment: You can add a custom toolbar as accessory view with done button to resignFirstResponder.

Comment: Have you set delegate of that textfield and add textFieldShouldReturn delegate method in your class file?

Comment: For return button in number pad you can add button in toolbar. Refer [show done button on iphone number pad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-done-button-on-iphone-number-pad)

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 7):

You want to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate //set delegate to class
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` set the textField delegate to self.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   textField.delegate = self
}
```

You can then add this method which runs when the return key is pressed, and `resignFirstResponder` which closes the keyboard:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For other newbies like myself, if you still don't have a keyboard on the simulator after following Joe's excellent instructions then go to the Simulator's menu and select Hardware/Keyboard/Toggle Software Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in Swift 4 it seems that the first parameter name of `textFieldShouldReturn` has to be omitted with an underscore. Elsewise Swift does not call the function:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField!) -> Bool { // use "_"
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Still can't get this to work. I am using the right delegate, have assigned the delegate in `viewDidLoad` - not being fired at all.