# Allow users to create simple fractions and mixed numbers in a nativescript mobile app

Tags: math, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I would like users of my Nativescript Angular 2 mobile app to be able to input fractions and mixed numbers and some other math symbols like exponents into a form. Using the standard keyboard in Android and IOS devices this does not appear to be possible. Is there some way that I can enable users to enter fractions in a form on the mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several keyboard types which are accessible through NativeScript with [KeyboardType](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_enums_.keyboardtype.html). Documentation article about using different keyboards [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/keyboard)

However, if you need even further extended keypad then you can create your own using native code. Some basics shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298824/nativescript-keyboard-for-negative-number-input-field)