# Done button in phone pad (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I was creating a registration form. I have a phone text field and when I open the phone pad, I can not see the done or return button so I can dismiss the on screen keyboard with `resignfirstresponder()`.

I used this link : https://gist.github.com/jplazcano87/8b5d3bc89c3578e45c3e

And now, I get the Done button but on pressing Done, my app is crashing because of the selector which says is unidentified. Can anyone please help or guide me with another way?

Thanks in advance

Here is the code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var registerTF: [KaustabhTF]!


    // MARK:-  App LifeCycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }


    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    // MARK:- User Defined

    func  isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {

        let emailRegEx = "^(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?(?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+(?:\\.[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+)*)|(?:\"(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:[!#-Z^-~]|\\[|\\])|(?:\\\\(?:\\t|[ -~]))))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)\"))(?:@)(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))))|(?:(?:(?: )*[!-Z^-~])*(?: )*)|(?:[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\\.[-A-Za-z0-9._~!$&'()*+,;=:]+))\\])))(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?$"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

        let result = emailTest.evaluate(with: email)

        return result

    }

    func isValidPassword(pass:String?) -> Bool {

        let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}")

        return passwordTest.evaluate(with: pass)
    }

    func displayAlert(alertMessage: String) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!!", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel,handler: nil))


        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()

        doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: Selector(("doneButtonAction")))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

        items.append(flexSpace)

        items.append(done)

        doneToolbar.items = items

        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.registerTF[5].inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

    }

    func doneButtonAction()
    {
        self.registerTF[5].resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func isValidPhone(value: String) -> Bool {

        let PHONE_REGEX = "^[0-9]{10}$"

        let phoneTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", PHONE_REGEX)

        let result =  phoneTest.evaluate(with: value)

        return result
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.view.endEditing(true) //This will hide the keyboard

    }

    let myPickerData =  [String](arrayLiteral: "+91", "+971", "+1", "+121", "+80", "+00")


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myPickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myPickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        registerTF[4].text = myPickerData[row]
    }

    func nextTextFieldToFirstResponder(textField: KaustabhTF) {

        if textField.absoluteCount() == 0
        {
            displayAlert(alertMessage: "Please enter the apt value.")
        }

        let senderTag = textField.tag

        if senderTag == 0           // Name
        {
            registerTF[senderTag + 1].becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        else if senderTag == 1      // Email
        {

            if !isValidEmail(email: textField.text!)
            {
                displayAlert(alertMessage: "Please input your valid email address")
            }

            else
            {
                registerTF[senderTag + 1].becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if senderTag == 2  // Password
        {

            if !isValidPassword(pass: textField.text)
            {
                displayAlert(alertMessage: "Please input a password with minimum of 8 characters including an upper case character, a lower case character and a digit.")
            }

            else
            {
                registerTF[senderTag + 1].becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if senderTag == 3 // Confirm Password
        {

            if !isValidPassword(pass: textField.text)
            {
                displayAlert(alertMessage: "Please input a password with minimum of 8 characters including an upper case character, a lower case character and a digit.")
            }

            else if registerTF[senderTag-1].text != registerTF[senderTag].text
            {
                displayAlert(alertMessage: "Password and confirm password dont match. Please try again")
            }

            else
            {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if senderTag == 4 //Country Code
        {
            let thePicker = UIPickerView()

            registerTF[4].inputView = thePicker

            thePicker.delegate = self

        }

        else if senderTag == 5 // Phone Number
        {
            self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()

            if !isValidPhone(value: textField.text!)
            {
                displayAlert(alertMessage: "Please make sure that the phone number is correct")
            }

                doneButtonAction()


        }

    }
```

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Comment: Added the code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show "Done" button on iPhone number pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-done-button-on-iphone-number-pad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Selector(("doneButtonAction"))
```

with

```
#selector(ViewController.doneButtonAction)
```

And complete code will be:

```
let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneButtonAction))
```

And add `@objc` before your `doneButtonAction` method and final code will be:

```
@objc func doneButtonAction()
{
    self.registerTF[5].resignFirstResponder()
}
```

For more info refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have two more issues. If you can solve, firstly I am running the simulator and when I click on the textfield, I get the phonepad WITHOUT the done button, but once I press the register button and again go to the Phone textfield then the Done button appears. I do not know why it is not appearing in the first place?

Comment: I can take a look if you can share demo project.

Comment: How can share it with you?

Comment: try this: call `self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()` method in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Wow! It's working thanks. What was the reason behind it's not working?

Comment: It wasn't working because you haven't assigned done button when view loads.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot man. Next issue is, in the senderTag == 4 you can see that I have inserted a picker view in the textfield and same thing is happening when the simulator loads I get the QWERTY keyboard or default keyboard instead of picker view and when I click the register button and again come to this textfield then the picker view arrives. How to solve this?

Comment: Zip your project and upload it here tinyupload.com and share a link

Comment: You can download it from address: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19536315212700139474

Comment: It's a different issue. I suggest check some tutorials on textField with picker view or ask a different question.

Comment: Okay, I will check on that. The other question is as you can see when I click on the lower textfield the keyboard overlaps or cuts the textfields and the register button, so, how can I move up the view when the keyboard comes up so that the textfields are not hidden any more?

Answer (score 2):

In **swift 3.0 and 4.0** you can used this code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtNumber: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()

    }

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(flexSpace)
        items.append(done)

        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.txtNumber.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

    }


    **//button action generate following two way both are working great but use any one**

    @objc func doneButtonAction()
    {
        self.txtNumber.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    @IBAction func doneButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.txtNumber.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate of this post: [How to show "Done" button on iPhone number pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-done-button-on-iphone-number-pad)

I have tried to add a duplicate flag, However I could not do it for some reason. Hope it will be helpful for others.