# How to put a button stick to the bottom with Weex on IOS?

Tags: ios, weex

I want to put a button stick to the bottom of the page when the input method is shown, I can do this on Android, but it's not working on IOS. Anyone knows how to do it?

target effect:
[image: target effect]

Comment: Somewhat similar - may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-done-button-on-iphone-number-pad

Comment: Please show the code